# customize the parameter of an object in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I need a function to convert the list array into the filtered object, which works to react**

```
const list = [{ id:1, name:"name1"}, { id:2, name:"name2"}]
filtered = {1:name1, 2:name2}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) for that, try this:

```js
const list = [{ id:1, name:"name1"}, { id:2, name:"name2"}]

const filtered = list.reduce((acc, {id, name}) => (acc[id] = name, acc), {});

console.log(filtered)
```