# Javascript transform list of objects into object with key value

Tags: javascript

`var mappings = [ { character: '1', symbol: '$' }, { character: 's', symbol: '@' } ]`

I want to turn this into:

```
{
  1: "$",
  s: "@"
}
```

Is there any easy way to accomplish this in JavaScript?

Comment: Yes, there is. You can use `forEach()` to loop over the array, then add the keys and values to the result object.

Comment: You could also use `map()` to return an array of arrays, and then use `Object.fromEntries()` to turn that into a new object.

Comment: You can even use a `for` loop if you prefer. All the basic operations are simple, what part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65924263/9765167

Comment: It's not that I don't know how to do it. I was wondering if there was a short way of doing it in JS. In C# I can just use ToDictionary(k => k.Character, v => v.Symbol) which makes it easy. So that the look up time is O(1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extract the values of each object in the array using `Array.prototype.map`, then construct an object from those entries using `Object.fromEntries`.

```js
var mappings = [ { character: '1', symbol: '$' }, { character: 's', symbol: '@' } ]

let result = Object.fromEntries(mappings.map(e => Object.values(e)))

console.log(result)
// output 
// { '1': '$', s: '@' }
```

---

NOTE the above code NOT WORKS if you have 2+ keys in each `mappings` item

Answer (score 1):

```js
var mappings = [ { character: '1', symbol: '$' }, { character: 's', symbol: '@' } ] 


const newMappings = mappings.map(item => ({[item.character] : item.symbol}))
const reduceMapping = newMappings.reduce((acc, current) => ({...acc, ...current}),{})

console.log(reduceMapping)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for me

Comment: @NamGVU neither this one "if you have 2+ keys in each mappings item".